# C program doesn't show expected output

Tags: c, netbeans, netbeans-8

I use NetBeans 8.2 to program in C language for university purposes but I have got a problem.
When I compile and run any program it does not show the correct output that would be `printf("Inserisci tre numeri\n")`.

Yet, I can enter
the parameters and, given the submission, the program shows the operation and instructions 
which I would like to make at the beginning.

Here's the full code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    float sum, prod;
    float med;

    printf("Inserisci tre numeri\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a,&b,&c);

    sum = a+b+c;
    prod = a*b*c;
    med = sum/3;

    printf("Somma=%.0f prodotto=%.0f media=%f\n", sum, prod, med);

    return 0;
}
```

[Here's the screen of the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxsEz.png)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? It shows the output "Inserisci tre numeri" which is what you printed...

Comment: This looks like output buffering issue in the NB console. Try forcing the flushing by `fflush(stdout)` after the printing.

Comment: Wrong, it does not show anything . When I write 3 numbers (which is the instruction about) it will show the output "Inserisci tre numeri".
In order it should be like:
Inserisci tre numeri:
1 2 3
Somma=6 prodotto=6 media=2.000000

Comment: Is it possible you, at one time, had the order of those lines of codes wrong and you haven't recompiled since correctly ordering them?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It works fine with that forcing command but I don't think it's a definitive solution to the problem!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Well, it's not just this program that shows an incorrect output. It looks like it's something to do with NetBeans :P

Comment: @NicodemoLucà As stated, this is a problem with your IDE. You can try to find a solution on IDE-related forums/sites. A compiled executable will behave correctly without `fflush`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Allright, thank you guys for the quick answers!

Comment: Just to be sure it's an issue with Netbeans' shell, it wouldn't hurt to try running the binary from the a regular terminal and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sure thing, Christian... just how do I do it?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Windows 10.

Comment: For that you'd want to load up the command prompt and navigate to the directory where your binary exists.  If you are not familiar with using the command prompt, you may want to find a tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Well, launching it from the command prompt it opens the notepad.

Comment: Did you launch the executable from command prompt, or did you launch the source file?